# Stretch the igraph graph

Tags: r, igraph

I have a graph similar to this one, it contains about 1000 vertices but text is pretty long. I'm looking for a way to plot it and see the text.

[image]

How to stretch the graph as much as possible to see the labels. Is it possible?

Comment: Try the `tkplot` command. You might find something useful here: http://igraph.org/r/doc/tkplot.html

Answer (score 0):

You likely have too many parameters to meaningfully be able to read any labels. However, you can specify a smaller font size, using:

```
plot(graph, vertex.label.cex = 0.5)
```

This will make all vertex labels 0.5 times the current size. See `?igraph.plotting` for more details.